# Find a real life example of floating point error

Tags: php, floating-point, ieee-754

The usual advice to handle money and other decimal numbers where accuracy is crucial is to either use integers or strings (plus arbitrary precision libraries) and it makes sense if you understand how floating point maths work. However, I don't have at hand any specific example to illustrate this, as every wrong calculation I've spot in the wild was due to some other mistake: naive comparisons using `==`, lack of proper rounding when displaying results, blatantly wrong logic (e.g. calculating taxes with an inconsistent algorithm that also doesn't work on paper)... I've done some research and results either only apply to C/C++ (float/double having different precision) or were mere elaborations on why you can't trust two floats to be equal.

Can you share a self-contained PHP code snippet with carefully selected floating point figures and a correct algorithm that renders an incorrect result explicitly caused by floating point limitations?

<sub>Disclaimer: I don't intend to argue, refute or debunk anything, I honestly need an example for my toolbelt.</sub>

Comment: Just write a loop which accumulates seconds/money/whatever in steps of `0.01` (and using any binary floating point format). Over time this will accumulate a significant error ("I heard" things like this did happen in-the-wild -- but I don't think finding references is on-topic here ...).

Comment: @chtz Thank you for the hint. I'll compose an answer with that, but I won't accept it yet since the example I came up with is not as practical as I'd had expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The question makes little sense because that isn't how floating point errors work.**

Inaccuracies are tiny. They happen in remote decimals and they're only noticeable when you require very high precision levels. After all, IEEE 754 powers a vast majority of computer systems and it offers an excellent precision. To put it in context, 0.1 kilometres expressed as float is 0.100000001490116119384765625, what makes accurate up to 1/10 of a µm
if I didn't get maths wrong.

There probably isn't a set of carefully chosen figures and a real-life calculation you'd be expected to use PHP for (an invoice, a stock exchange index...) that renders incorrect results no matter how careful you are with precision levels. Because that's not the problem.

**The problem with floating point maths is that it forces you to be extremely careful on every step and it makes it very easy for bugs to slip in.**

For applications where accuracy matters, you *can* write correct software using floats, but it won't be as easy, maintainable or robust.

---

Original answer:

This is the best I've got so far (thanks to [chtz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6870253/chtz) for the hint):

```
// Set-up and display settings (shouldn't affect internal calculations or final result)
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('precision', -1);

// Expected accuracy: 2 decimal positions
$total = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < 1e9; $i++) {
    $total += 0.01;
    // It's important to NOT round inside the loop, e.g.: $total = round($total + 0.01, 2);
}
var_dump($total, number_format($total, 2));
```

```
float(9999999.825158669)
string(12) "9,999,999.83" // Correct value would be "10,000,000.00"
```

Unfortunately, it relies on the accumulation of a very large number of precision errors (it needs around 1,000,000,000 of them to happen and it needs more than 4 minutes to run in my PC), so it isn't as real-life as I would have liked, but it certainly illustrates the underlying issue.

Comment: Off by only 17 ulps after a billion terms.  There is probably a lot of cancelation going on, but I don't see an easy way to avoid it.  If you could somehow avoid such, you still might need a million items on your cash register to be off by a penny.  (Only CVS has that much paper.)

Comment: " so it isn't as real-life" -->  Hmmm.  See [Rounding errors on its Index price](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vancouver_Stock_Exchange#Rounding_errors_on_its_Index_price)   Some real life FP problems take time.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Remember the question context. A typical PHP process lifetime is a few seconds, some hours at most, certainly never *years*. It's not about "are floating point errors a thing?" but about finding a concrete piece of code that exhibits the issue.

Comment: The loop-example would be the easiest way to show the effect. A slightly more real example would perhaps involve storing floats in a database and updating them depending on some request (and having multiple requests per minute/per second). It might then take several weeks/months until the error is noticeably (but these subtle errors are often worse than obvious errors, because they can be hidden while everything "almost works").

Answer (score 0):

Things can break fairly easy with much less than a billion iterations. The thing is, by using floats and arithmetic you can very easily find yourself with unexpected results, and even if numbers superficially *look* fine, the subtle imprecisions can lead to an application bugging out.

Let's try a variation of the example in your answer:

```php
$total = 0.0;
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $total += 0.1;
}

echo "added ten cents, ten times\n";

// since we added 0.1 € x 10 times, we now have 1€ in total, right?
if ($total == 1) {
    echo "I have 1€. All is good in the realm.";
}
else {
    echo "WTF? Where is my money? I only have {$total}€!!!!\n";
    echo "\$total holds: ";
    var_dump($total);
}
```

The output for the above is:

```
added ten cents
WTF? Where is my money? I only have 1€!!!!
$total holds: float(1)
```

Even if `$total` appears to be `float(1)`, the code follow the 'wrong' branch of execution, breaking our application.

If we execute the same code in PHP8 (beta so far), you'll an easier to understand result:

```
added ten cents
WTF? Where is my money? I only have 1€!!!!
$total holds: float(0.9999999999999999)
```

Another simple example:

```
$balance          = 50.03;
$debit            = 45.42;
$expected_balance = 4.61;
$real_balance     = $balance - $debit;

if ($real_balance !== $expected_balance) {
    echo "problems: ";
    var_dump($real_balance);
}
```

The output for the above is:

```
balance mismatch: float(4.61)
```

or, in PHP8:

```
balance mismatch: float(4.609999999999999)
```

Either of the above examples show that practically, using floating numbers to do (specifically) money arithmetic can be problematic. Since the results no longer match your expectations, not only it can lead to plainly wrong results, but the subtle different results can make the whole application behaving in unexpected ways.

Examples and results, [here](https://3v4l.org/3Ya5L).

Comment: This information is indeed valuable and something anyone handling floats needs to be fully aware of—but not what I was asking (thus my references to "naive comparisons using ==, lack of proper rounding when displaying results"). I admit anyway that I asked the question because I thought floating point errors took other forms and perhaps they don't, they just make the issues you describe easier to happen.

Comment: The second example uses a strict comparison (`!==`). The first example would behave exactly the same using a strict comparison (`===`). I just use a laxer comparison to show that even then the error occurs. This is exactly the kind of rounding error will pop-up using floating point arithmetic. And it's indeed practical, as it's very likely something like this could happen in real life. If this is not what you are looking for, I'm at a loss.

Comment: By rounding output you are logically masking imprecision, but errors may happen before you get to that point, as demonstrated above.

Comment: I wasn't referring to PHP loose typing. The proper way to compare floats for equity is to use an epsilon, as in `$isEqual = abs($f1 – $f2) <= $epsilon`.

Comment: As about what I'm looking for, it's just a real life example, i.e., a code snippet that performs a real task (as opposed to some imaginary problem) followings the basic floating point maths guidelines yet renders incorrect results. But, as I said, I suspect I won't find any because that isn't where the problem is.

Comment: The code in your answer performs a "real task", and not an "imaginary problem"? Not clear what do you mean by "real life example", unless it's code copied from an existing tool or library, which would make the question off-topic in any case.

Comment: Not, the code in my answer doesn't comply with that because I can't conceive a PHP job assignment where I need to sum a billion floats and also requires skipping intermediate rounding to "work". I've shared it because it's my best attempt so far, but I haven't tagged it as accepted answer for that reason. To set an analogy out of computers realm, it's possible to find some carefully chosen figures to illustrate rounding issues in tax calculations.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo floor((0.1 + 0.7) * 10);
```

Expected result: 0.1 + 0.7 = 0.8; 0.8 * 10 = 8;

Result: 7

Tested on PHP 7.2.12

Comment: According to docs https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php *Returns the next lowest integer value*. So as 0.7 and 0.1 do not have only one digit after dot, result is lower than 8, which is floor'ed to 7.